# How to rename worksheet incrementally based on cell value in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with multiple values but the same structure through out. I want to rename the worksheet based on the cell value "E1".

However, there are multiple sheets with the same value in E1. How can I rename the worksheet abc01 (if cell E1=abc) and the corresponding sheets with cell E1= abc as abc02 and so on.

I have tried

```
Sub RenameWorksheet()

Dim WS As Worksheet
     For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            WS.Name = WS.Range("E1").Value
     Next WS
End Sub
```

This code fails if i have more than one sheet with the same value in cell E1

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: You need to add If statements and check if the sheet name already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
Sub ReNameSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
Dim shIdx As Long
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If InStr(LCase(ws.Name), LCase(ws.Range("E1").Value)) = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If InStr(LCase(Sheets(i).Name), LCase(ws.Range("E1").Value)) > 0 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                If Right(Sheets(i).Name, 2) > shIdx Then shIdx = Right(Sheets(i).Name, 2)
            End If
        Next i
        If cnt > 0 Then
            cnt = shIdx + 1
            ws.Name = ws.Range("E1").Value & Format(cnt, "00")
        Else
            ws.Name = ws.Range("E1").Value & "01"
        End If

        cnt = 0
        shIdx = 0
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a counter variable and increment that variable in your For Each Loop.  After that you can append the number to the value of E1.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, sheet names must be unique. You can add the Index to the end of the name if that name already exists.

```
Sub RenameWorksheet()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each WS In .Worksheets
            WS.Name = WS.Range("E1").Value & IIf(Exists(WS.Range("E1").Value), WS.Index, vbNullString)
        Next WS
    End With
End Sub

Function Exists(ByVal Name As String) As Boolean
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each WS In .Worksheets
            If WS.Name = Name Then
                Exists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next WS
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @kostas K. I am getting a runtime error 9 for both the solutions. I did not know on the concept of index... Many thanks for bringing that out as well.

Comment: @ThePatBan Indeed, see updated answer. A helper function is required to check if name exists.